# Underscore.js - groupBy with nested array

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

I was struggling with grouping my categories array in a collection like this example:

```
 var programs = [
   {
    name: 'a',
    categories: ['cat1', 'cat2']
   },
   {
    name: 'b',
    categories: ['cat2']
   },
   {
    name: 'c',
    categories: ['cat1', 'cat3']   
   }
];
```

If you do:

```
_.groupBy(programs, function(item){ return item.categories; });
```

It returns:

```
{
  'cat1, cat2': Array[1],
  'cat1, cat3': Array[1],
  'cat2': Array[1]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After searching over the Internet I tried it by my own and played with Underscore.js

Finally I got the solution which works for me:

```
var group = _.groupBy(_.flatten(_.pluck(programs, 'categories')), function(item){
    return item;
});
```

This returns:

```
{
  'cat1': Array[2], 
  'cat2': Array[2], 
  'cat3': Array[1]
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pypurjf3/2/

I hope this will help some people struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Nice timing :-) Exactly what I was looking for (literally, I had also multiple categories).

Comment: Apparently this doesn't solve my case, but regardless, gave insight and idea to pursue forward.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for me? maybe i can help you.

Comment: but the array inside each key shows , for example: ['cat1', 'cat1'], and not the object you want. So, at the end, is not grouping  your objects by categories. Did you find another way after this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but wanted to do a bit more with how the grouping came out.  Here's what I ended up with:

```js
function groupByNested(theList, whichValue) {
  // Extract unique values, sort, map as objects
  var groups = _.chain(theList).pluck(theList, whichValue).flatten().uniq().reject(function(v) { return v==''; }).sort().map(function(g) { return { group: g, items: [] }; }).value();
  
  // Iterate through the array and add applicable items into the unique values list
  _.each(_ls.plants, function(p) {
    _.each(p[whichValue], function(v) {
      theGroup = _.find(groups, function(g) { return g.group == v; });
      theGroup.items.push(p);
    });
  });
  return groups;
}
```